# How to tranform a column field into a list using Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-9.3, python-parser, error-000539

I'm trying to make a simple field calculation with ArcGIS 9.3:

New field = Old field - Old field(first value)

which in Calculate Field with python code should be

Expression:

```
!Old field!  - first
```

Code Block:

```
list= [AngOriz]
first = list[0]
```

The error is

> ERROR 000539: Runtime error : name
>   'AngOriz' is not defined Failed to execute (Calculate Field).

How could I transform a column field into a list?

Comment: Have you thought about using an update cursor to iterate through your rows and calculate your new field that way?

Comment: I'm having a bear of a time understanding this. Could you give us a sample of the data and explain what the calculation should result in if it works properly?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain I understand the problem, but I asked a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8695/basic-field-calculator-python-question) here previously about the syntax when using the Python Codeblock. The key misunderstanding I had was that you need to pass in your field names as arguments to the code block. Here is a small example:

[image]

and the corresponding part of the attribute table:

[image]

In your case, I think the easiest thing would be to make a new field with the value from `Old field(first value)`, and then use that for the calculation. This would not require putting python in the codeblock.