# Concatenate only when all fields to be concatenated have values

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

I have two fields that I want to concatenate.  Field1 contains null values and Field2 has values for every record.  I want to concatenate only when both fields have values.  I tried using a function with an `if/else` statement but that doesn't work as the resulting concatenation will return values from field2.

```
def concat_fields(field1, field2):
    if field1 == ""
        return 

    else:
        return field1 + field2
```

I know this is wrong.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: If one field is empty do you want to return an empty string or the unconcatenated value of the other field? I would have thought the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your results, it looks like field1 may have a space (" ") in the field, instead of an empty string.

```
def concat_fields(field1, field2):
    if field1.strip() == "" or field2.strip() == "":
        return ""
    else:
        return field1 + field2
```

Comment: Great, this worked.  But I had to return an empty string - `return ""` - for it to work as I was getting an error `The field is not nullable`

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code on my end to return the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mean empty strings "" instead of NULL, you are missing just a 'or' operator:

```
def concat_fields(field1, field2):
  if field1 == "" or field2 == "":
      return 

  else:
      return field1 + field2
```

Comment: hmmm, i'm still getting values from field2 even if field1 has empty strings. The expression i'm using is `concat_fields(!FIELD1!, !FIELD2!)`

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. I've two fields to concatenate, exluding empty values. The fields are:
AREA_HI
AREA_LO

But arcgis return an error "000539 : Error message from Python."

Some suggestions? Thank's.

```
def concat_fields(!AREA_HI!, !AREA_LO!):
    if !AREA_HI!.strip() == "" or !AREA_LO!.strip() == "":
        return ""
    else:
        return !AREA_HI! + !AREA_LO!
```

Comment: Please consider posting your question as a new question to give it more exposure, rather than in an answer to an existing question. This might help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8695/basic-field-calculator-python-question